# I can't scrape this website using Google Sheets IMPORTXML - is scraping blocked?

Tags: xml, xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to scrape [this website](http://poe.trade/search/roumedomigoniu) using the ImportXML function on Google Sheets and although I can get info from the "head" tag, I can't get anything from the "body" tag.

For example, the function to get the title should be

```
=importxml("link","//html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/h3/a")
```

But I get an `#N/A "Imported content is empty"`. I have tried scraping everything under the "body" tag with no success. Just "/body" does not return an error, but it does give me an empty cell. I am wondering if scraping onto Google sheets is just blocked here. Thank you in advance.

Comment: what exactly you want to scrape?

Comment: Specifically, I would like to scrape all of "prices" beside the "fixed price" text in each box. But I am unable to scrape anything in "body" tag right now at all

Answer (score 0):

you can scrape only what you see on this image:

[image: 0]

if so, then you need to use this formula:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA("http://poe.trade/search/roumedomigoniu"), 3000, 10)
```

and with combo of `QUERY` and `REXEXREPLACE`/`REGEXEXTRACT` filter out what you need directly from the source code.